# RadioButton not getting current selected value, showing the previous value

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to get the value of the radiobutton selected, but I am getting the previous value, not the current one.

I have used asp.net radiobuttonlist.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="toggleDisplay" AutoPostBack="true">
                                <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                             <br />
```

Jquery:
I have tried these, both give previous value

```
 $(".toggleDisplay").click(function () {
                    var groupName = $(this).find(":radio").attr('name');
                    var ans = $('input[name="' + groupName + '"]:radio:checked').val();

  });

                $("#<%=rdbList.ClientID%>").click(function () {
                    var rbvalue = $("input[name='<%=rdbList.UniqueID%>']:radio:checked").val();
                    $("input[name='<%=rdbList.UniqueID%>']:checked").val();
                });
```

I am not sure, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: why AutoPostback="true"? do you want to submit the page when selection gets changed? and why two javascript functions for same thing?

Comment: I forgot to remove autopost back. I was just showing all the options I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. Link to working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xcjw6aah/)**. Also note that you've set `AutoPostBack = true` which may not be necessary unless you are doing some server side operation at the code behind.

```
 $(".toggleDisplay").click(function () {
      alert($('input[name=rdbList]:checked').val());
 });
```

Comment: Actually the issue was due to Zurb foundation radio buttons, I was using. Even though I had the click event wired up correctly, it still wouldn't take the current value. Commented out that code and everything worked fine.